# Class#isAnnotationPresent not working

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I'm searching through a list of classes to check if a class has a Annonation. This is the code:

```
                        if (clazz.getAnnotations().length > 0){
                            System.out.println(clazz.getAnnotations()[0]);
                        }
                        if (clazz.isAnnotationPresent(Manifest.class)){
                            System.out.println(clazz.getName());
                        }
```

The first if statement is just for debugging. One class prints:

```
@bot.script.Manifest(description=test, version=1.0, name=test)
```

This is exactly the same as Manifest.class, but why is clazz.isAnnotationPresent not working?

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the same `Manifest` class in both cases?

Comment: Yes, it prints: bot.script.Manifest. And I've imported bot.script.Manifest for Manifest.class

Comment: Do you have several classloaders? What do `System.out.println(class.getAnnotations()[0].getClassLoader())` and `System.out.println(Manifest.class.getClassLoader())` print? Are the two class loaders the same?

Comment: how do you get `clazz` ?

Comment: @JochemGruter: Ok.  If it's not a classloader issue (as described by JB Nizet), then can you construct a minimal example?  (For reference, here's an example that works: http://ideone.com/1lz0IJ).

Comment: JB Nizet, no it has not the same classloader

Comment: Then you have your answer. The same class Manifest is loaded twice, by two different class loaders. Make sure only one classloader can load the class. For example, if run in a webapp, the class should be in the container's claspath, or in the webapp's classpath (WEB-INF/classes and WEB-INF/lib/xxx.jar), but not in both.

Comment: @JBNizet: You should probably make that an answer (unless this question is a duplicate...)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth; you're right. I've made it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, it looks like you have several class loaders. The annotated class and its Manifest annotation are loaded by a first class loader, and the class containing the `if` tests in your question is loaded by a second class loader, and reloads the Manifest class using this second class loader.

As a consequence, you test if `Manifest.class` is the same as `clazz.getAnnotations()[0]`, and they are not, because although they have the same name, they're two different classes because loaded by two different class loaders.

It's hard to tell you how to fix the problem, because we don't know what your application does, how it does it and in which environment. But you should make sure only one classloader can load the class.

For example, if run in a webapp, the class should be in the container's claspath, or in the webapp's classpath (WEB-INF/classes and WEB-INF/lib/xxx.jar), but not in both.